# How to call validation message for checking character count in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have used sharepoint 'Pagestategroupcheckin' command on button click on my page. It opens the check in popup. When I type more than 1023 character and checkin the page, It doesn't trigger the validation message. I need message as it's limitation for sharepoint check-in field can't save more than 1023 characters.

I have called Javascript function on button click and used below SharePoint default ribbon action in JavaScript function call:

```
SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog("PageStateGroupCheckin", SP.Ribbon.PageState.ImportedNativeData.CommandHandlers["PageStateGroupCheckin"])
```

Comment: Can you share what you have code wise

Comment: I have updated the code and specified in question.